# Running function recursively is causing undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm getting a weird error here:

```
function clickSubmit(j){
    var times = document.getElementById("times").value;
    if (j == times){
        return;
    }
    var myWindow = window.open("http://www.w3schools.com","_blank");
    console.log(myWindow);
    setTimeout(function(){
        myWindow.close();
        clickSubmit(j+1);
    }, 1000);
}
```

What it basically does (should do) is opening the window as many times as given in value `times`. The problem is on first run i see the output from console giving `myWindow` a value, however on the second run it's `undefined` (when `clickSubmit(j+1)` is called). I can't give `myWindow` as a global variable as it has to change according to the times, so it has to be in that spot, although i can't figure out why should something like this happen.

Comment: @Tushar Here in banana's case, return is not required, I guess.

Comment: @Tushar `return`does not fix this issue

Comment: Working fine https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/pa1n28se/

Comment: Just second ago figured out it myself aswell, chrome thought i'm sending pop-ups from the page and disabled them, after allowing them all the objects appeared, wow..

Comment: @Banana will eat you if you bring this kind of issues here :)

Comment: Without making `myWindow` global you will get this error;